# Why Vue app is not mounted on refresh?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have Vuejs SPA app with the following code:

```
...
import Rides from './components/rides'
import RideInfo from './components/ride_info'
...

//Defining router
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        { path: '/rides/:car', component: Rides, name: 'rides' },
        { path: '/ride_info/:ride_index', component: RideInfo, name: 'ride_info' }
    ]
});

//Defining vuex store
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        isLoggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem("token"),
        data: {}
    },
    mutations: {
        login (state) {
            state.isLoggedIn = true;
        },
        logout (state) {
            state.isLoggedIn = false;
        },
        set_initial_data(state, data) {
            state.data = data;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        login({ commit }, token) {
            localStorage.setItem("token", token);
            commit("login");
        },
        logout({ commit }) {
            localStorage.removeItem("token");
            commit("logout");
        },
        set_initial_data({commit}, data) {
            commit("set_initial_data", data);
        }
    },
    getters: {
        isLoggedIn: state => {
            return state.isLoggedIn
        },
        data: state => {
            return state.data
        }
    }
});

//Starting the app
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    mounted: function() {
        console.log("app mounted");
        var that = this;
        $.get("/initial_data/", {}, function(data) {
            that.$store.dispatch('set_initial_data', data);
        });
    }
}).$mount('#app');
```

When I go to http://localhost:8000/rides/123 and refresh, I get into the mounted function and get the initial data as I should.

When I go to http://localhost:8000/ride_info/123 and refresh I don't get into the mounted function and not bringing the data.

Any idea why this is happening and how can I make the app go to mounted function on every refresh regardless of url?

Comment: Do you have the [required server-side URL rewrites](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html) in place? If so, what does the configuration look like?

Comment: This sounds like a pushstate/history issue, although I could be wrong. Is this happening in development or production? Check the docs here for help: http://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: Thanks guys. The problem happens locally so there is no apache/nginx.... Also tried to remove "mode:'history'" and I see the same problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: Ok. Found the problem. Inside the component I tried to access store data during the template render and it happened before i got the data from my ajax request to the server. Stupid me, but thanks for the help anyway!